# When a task is resumed by a user, different from the owner, does it execute with the privileges of the creator?

Tags: task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a task which calls a SP which in turns does DML operations on objects. The task is owned by USER1. When USER2 resumes the task, does it require all required privileges to complete the process (usage on SP, DML privileges on affected objects)?

Or whoever resumes a task, it only gets executed with its owner's right?

Comment: Yes, the individual DML operations would require it's respective privileges to be provided to the user which is resuming the task.

Comment: just for clarity....objects in Snowflake are never owned by a user.  They are always owned by the role.

Comment: Thanks @MikeWalton. I miswrote it as users but it would be different roles only.